# Bootstrap not allows to post data from html in django

Tags: django, post

{% csrf_token %}
    
        
        
            User name

```
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="form2Example2">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="form2Example2" class="form-control" name="password" required/>

    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Sign in</button>
```

i try to post data like email id and password in post method , but it sent through get method . I think there may be problem with bootstrap. can u tell me what are the modifications to be done in the bootstrap for post data method.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send it as post, then use button type: `"submit"`. Also you might need `form` section, if you don't have it. Like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        (...)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `method = "POST"` with {% csrf_token %} and submit button

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Signin</button>
  </form>
```